# Windows api dll library load guide

Tags: go

I want to know guide for load dll library with golang. For example how I can load `RtlAdjustPrivilege(int Privilege, bool bEnablePrivilege, bool IsThreadPrivilege, out bool PreviousValue)` from `ntdll.dll`

So for I know

```
c := syscall.MustLoadDLL("ntdll.dll").MustFindProc("RtlAdjustPrivilege")
_, _, err = c.Call()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few guides on the topic.

**The Golang wiki** on Github has a rather decent introduction to importing Windows DLLs into Go programs, check it out: 
https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/WindowsDLLs

That ends with a link to **cgo Documentation**, where you will learn how to use C to import Windows DLLs from Go programs:
https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/cgo

Good luck!

Comment: I will try all day but nothing. That's all I want is know what difference between uintptr(unsafe.Pointer()) and uintptr() and why all values must be uintptr and why I cannot enter bool value and what I do with out values of library?

Comment: Can you example for RtlAdjustPrivilege?